# Facebook Api null exception

Tags: restfb

I'm trying to get like data or comment data but the `.getData()` always 
return null and i don't know why

My code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            FacebookClient fClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("blabla");

            Page page = fClient.fetchObject("me", Page.class);

            System.out.println(page.getName());

            Connection<Post> data = fClient.fetchConnection("me/posts", Post.class);

            for (Post p : data.getData())
            {
                for (LikeItem like : p.getLikes().getData())
                {
                    System.out.println(like.getName());
                }
            }
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Parameter.with("fields","likes")` in your `fetchConnection` call. Facebook only returns values that are asked by you. Check the introduction section in our documentation here: https://restfb.com/documentation/#fetching